# Query CSV and write original CSV and results to single CSV Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, csv

I am trying to parse a CSV and if criteria are met in either column write this out to a new csv.

For example

If I have a csv that looks like

```
123 Some Street
Flat 1, 21 Other road
House, Someother street
```

I need to analyse each line so if a number appears in the first column and not the second then I need to extract that number, if there is a number in both columns then I need to extract both and if there is no number then I need to extract the text in the first column.
Then write a new csv with the 2 original columns and 3 new ones number 1, number 2, text. ie flat number, house number, house name.
So the new CSV would look like

```
123 Some Street, , 123, 
Flat 1, 21 Other road, 1, 21,
House, Someother street, , , House.
```

Any guidance would be very helpful.

Thanks

Edited

```
import csv

csvFile = 'myData.csv'
csvOut = 'myOut.csv'

reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
writer = csv.writer(csvOut)

for row in reader:
    num = \d | \d\d | \d\d\d
     if row [0] || row [1] == num
        if row [1] == num
            writer.row [3]
        else row [0] == num
            writer.row [2]
            writer.row [3]
    else writer.row [0] [2]

csvOut.close()
```

Edited again

I hope that this might be a clearer explination:

I would like to have the output be a new CSV with the original data in row [0],[1] and then if there is only one number in the row ie the house number that is written to row [3], if there are 2 numbers in a row (row[0] and row [1]) then they should be written to row [2] and [3] respectively and if there is no number then the string from row [0] written to row [4]. Ultimately I need to separate flat number, house number and house name into 3 different columns.

A further edit

I have been working on the code and now have the following, I feel I am getting closer but still a way away?

```
import csv
import re

csvFile = open(myData.csv, 'rb')
csvOut = open(myOut.csv, 'wb')

reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
writer = csv.writer(csvOut)

for row in reader:
    a = row [0] re.compile('\d' | '\d\d' | '\d\d\d')
    a1 = row [0] re.compile('\d' | '\d\d' | '\d\d\d')
    b = row [1] 
    b1 = row [1] re.compile('\d' | '\d\d' | '\d\d\d')
        if b = re.compile('\d' | '\d\d' | '\d\d\d')
            writer.writerow(a,b,a1,b1, )
        elif a = re.compile('\d' | '\d\d' | '\d\d\d')
            witer.writerow(a,b, , b1, )
        else
            writer.writerow(a,b, , ,a)

csvOut.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: Start by working with the examples in the documentation of [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: Firstly, thank you for editing. I have had a good look through the CSV and the csv.dictreader currently my issue is around how to extract the items, the logic / regex needed. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you have now?

Comment: I know it is not right I am just not sure how to go about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might give a clue as I'm not wholly sure what you need.

`$cat t1`

```
123 Some Street
Flat 1, 21 Other road
House, 23 Someother street
```

Example

```
import csv
import re
p = re.compile('\d+')
for row in csv.reader(open('t1')):
    print "ROW", row
    match = p.search(row[0])
    if match:
        print "\t#1", match.group()
    if len(row) > 1:
        match = p.search(row[1])
        if match:
            print "\t#2", match.group()
```

Output

```
ROW ['123 Some Street']
    #1 123
ROW ['Flat 1', ' 21 Other road']
    #1 1
    #2 21
ROW ['House', ' 23 Someother street']
    #2 23
```

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful. I made an error in the original which did not help (I have corrected it). I would like to have the output be a new CSV with the original data in row [0],[1] and then if there is only one number in the row ie the house number that is written to row [3], if there are 2 numbers in a row then they should be written to row [2] and [3] respectively and if there is no number then the string from row [0] written to row [4]. Ultimately I need to separate flat number, house number and house name into 3 different columns. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code may do everything you need.  For output, simply index the tuple and write out the components you want. Each result has 6 elements

```
#(flat str, flat #, street str, street #, street, street type)

a = """
123 Some Street
Flat 1, 21 Other road
House, Someother street
"""

import re
#flat gets a word, 0 or more spaces, 0 or more digits
flat    = "([a-z]+ *(\d+)*)"
#street gets 0 or more digits, 1 or more spaces, 1 or more words with a space consuming until it hits street, or road or drive
street  = "((\d+)* +([a-z]+ )+?(street|road|drive))"
address = "%s*.*?%s" % (flat,street)
m       = re.compile(r"%s" % address, re.I)
results = m.findall(a)
with('output.csv','w') as fout:
    #whatever you wish to name your columns
    fout.write("Building,Address,Suite Number, Building Number")
    for r in results:
        fout.write("%s,%s,%s,%s" % (r[0],r[2],r[1],r[3]))
```

results

```
[('', '', '123 Some Street', '123', 'Some ', 'Street'),
 ('Flat 1', '1', '21 Other road', '21', 'Other ', 'road'),
 ('House', '', ' Someother street', '', 'Someother ', 'street')]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am very new to python, could you please point me in the right direction as to how to write it out.

Comment: The post has been updated to output the results.  google 'python re' to learn more about regex if you're interested, it's one of the most useful things I've learned.