# Text file creation issue where new lines created when not really EOL

Tags: python, xml, regex, csv, cygwin

I am importing some text data from a set of files I have created in python (converting metadata/xml records to text) into excel. It mostly works fine except that there are new lines inserted at points where the text is simply in a paragraph. This is an issue in the file creation process.

Is it possible to clean the data automatically to maintain data in the same row until it meets an escape/new character?

As this site doesn't allow attachments I have attached examples [here.](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/905025-import-txt-to-table-issue-with-new-lines-created-when-not-eol.html?p=3148886#post3148886)

1. anz*_log.txt -- Raw text file where I am using "^" as the delimiter. I can force it to add another character at the end of each known row if excel can use this to only create new lines when this exists.
2. anz*_xml.xls Excel Import - worksheet (*log) the raw import data) and cleaned where I have used formulas to get the values in properly.
3. rowChar_anz*log.txt - Raw text file with ':;:' at start of each row to show that it should be a new row (same as 1 but with additional delimiter for row)

This is just on a test dataset and I need to run this on 1000's of files. See the issues in row 9,13, 54 etc.

Can I use python (or if necessary cygwing/SED) to

1. Look for the "start of line" string - ':;:' and "end of line" string ';:;'
2. If both don't exist in a single row then append line to previous row

Alternatively (and ideally) Can this be done while the file is being created using the following code? maybe using re.compile (as in [Query CSV and write original CSV and results to single CSV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863627/query-csv-and-write-original-csv-and-results-to-single-csv-python))?

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        Convert xml data to csv with anzlic tagged data kept seperate
# Purpose:  Also has an excel template to convert the data into standard columns
#
# Author:      georgec@atgis.com.au
#
# Created:     05/03/2013
# Copyright:   (c) ATGIS. georgec 2013
# Licence:     Creative Commons
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import os, xml, shutil, datetime
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

SourceDIR=r'L:\Vector_Data'
rootDir=os.getcwd()
log_name='vector'
x=0

def locatexml(SourceDIR,x, rootDir):
    xmllist=[]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SourceDIR, topdown=False):
        for fl in files:
            currentFile=os.path.join(root, fl)
            ext=fl[fl.rfind('.')+1:]
            if ext=='xml':
                xmllist.append(currentFile)
                print currentFile
                x+=1
                try:
                    processxml(currentFile,x, rootDir)
                except:
                    print "Issue with file: "+ currentFile
                    log=open(rootDir+'\\'+log_name+'issue_xml_log.txt','a')
                    log.write(str(x)+'^'+currentFile+'\n')
                    log.close

    print "finished"
    return xmllist, x, currentFile

def processxml(currentFile,x, rootDir):
    from lxml import etree
    seperator='^'
    with open(currentFile) as f:
        tree = etree.parse(f)
    xmltaglist=[]
    for tagn in tree.iter(tag=None):
        #print tagn.tag
        xmltaglist.append(tagn.tag)
    if 'anzmeta' in str(tree.getroot()):
        log=open(rootDir+'\\'+log_name+'anzmeta_xml_log.txt','a')
        log.write(':;:'+seperator+str(x)+seperator+currentFile+seperator)
        for xmltag in xmltaglist:
            for element in tree.iter(xmltag):
                #print element[x]
                for child in element.getchildren():
                    print "{0.tag}: {0.text}".format(child)
                    log.write("{0.tag}".format(child)+"::"+"{0.text}".format(child)+seperator)
        log.write('\n')
        log.close
    else:
        print currentFile+" not an anzlic metadata file...logging seperately"
        log=open(rootDir+'\\'+log_name+'non_anzmeta_xml_log.txt','a')
        log.write(':;:'+seperator+str(x)+seperator+currentFile+seperator)
        for xmltag in xmltaglist:
            for element in tree.iter(xmltag):
                #print element[x]
                for child in element.getchildren():
                    print "{0.tag}: {0.text}".format(child)
                    log.write("{0.tag}".format(child)+"::"+"{0.text}".format(child)+seperator)
        log.write('\n')
        log.close

locatexml(SourceDIR,x, rootDir)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer....simply added .replace('\n','') to command that wrote each entry. Should have thought of this a few hours ago!!!