# Consistently order columns from a dsv (text file) where each record has a different column order

Tags: python, database, excel

=== Comment regarding closing question ====

While the data in the example is localized the final script will be useful for anyone who has a complex set of xml files to convert to a text database as the process will work on any input xml regardless of the attribution.

=== New Information ====
I have been able to generate a list of all the tags in the initial process but to then recreate the tag::text pairs is not feasible as it has to run through 1000's of xml's, produce a unique sorted list and then re-read the xml's and start to create the text datasets.

So if given the following (or any text with unique delimiters) can I run through and capture the tags?

```
:;:^1^L:\Vector_Data\Administrative\Boundaries\Federal_Govt\COM_ELB_region.shp_BaseMetadata.xml^citeinfo::None^descript::None^timeperd::None^status::None^distinfo::None^dataqual::None^cntinfo::None^metainfo::None^uniqueid::None^title::COM_ELB_region.shp^origin::None^custod::Tablelands Regional Council ^jurisdic::None^;:;
```

(in this case ^ is the column separator and :: is the tag::text separator)

I need it to give me a list of tags like [citeinfo, timeprd, status etc] and then run through and create another dataset which has just the text.

I will stress that this is not localized as the solution will work on any xml's that need deconstruction.

=== Original Question follows

I have created a text file by de constructing a number of different xml style documents. I have recorded the tag::text together as each file has the tags in a slightly different order. The key is the name of the original xml file.

Is it possible to reconstruct an excel or 'csv' from the data so that all files have the columns properly ordered.

An excel sample and raw data is available [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/905025-import-txt-to-table-issue-with-new-lines-created-when-not-eol.html?p=3150342#post3150342). The script I used is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283801/text-file-creation-issue-where-new-lines-created-when-not-really-eol).

Thanks,

====
It is to difficult to get a list of tags from the output as you would need to go line by line and search for the tags and if not duplicate add to a list. So I decided that it's easier to generate a tag list while parsing the xml. This worked but I am having issues with telling the script what do when a tag from the ordered list is not found in the xml. See code below.

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        Convert xml data to csv with anzlic tagged data kept seperate
# Purpose:  Also has an excel template to convert the data into standard columns
#
# Author:      georgec@atgis.com.au
#
# Created:     05/03/2013
# Copyright:   (c) ATGIS. georgec 2013
# Licence:     Creative Commons
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import os, xml, shutil, datetime
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
from lxml import etree

SourceDIR=r'L:\Data_Admin\XML_CSV_Convertor\test_data'
#SourceDIR=os.getcwd()
rootDir=os.getcwd()
log_name='t2_'
xmllist=[]
xmltaglist=[]
x=0

def locatexml(SourceDIR,x, rootDir, xmllist, xmltaglist):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SourceDIR, topdown=False):
        for fl in files:
            currentFile=os.path.join(root, fl)
            ext=fl[fl.rfind('.')+1:]
            if ext=='xml':
                xmllist.append(currentFile)
                print currentFile
                x+=1
##            try:
                processxmltag(currentFile,x, rootDir, xmltaglist)
##            except:
##                print "Issue with file: "+ currentFile
##                log=open(rootDir+'\\'+log_name+'issue_xml_log.txt','a')
##                log.write(str(x)+'^'+currentFile+'\n')
##                log.close

    print "finished"
    return xmllist, x, currentFile

def processxmltag(currentFile,x, rootDir, xmltaglist):
    from collections import OrderedDict
    with open(currentFile) as f:
        tree = etree.parse(f)
    for tagn in tree.iter(tag=None):
        if tagn.tag not in xmltaglist:
            print tagn.tag
            xmltaglist.append(tagn.tag)
        else:
            print 'tag exists: ' + str(tagn.tag)
    return xmltaglist.sort()

def processxmlfile(xmllist, xmltaglist):
    seperator='^'
    for fl in xmllist:
        with open(fl) as f:
            tree = etree.parse(f)
            if 'anzmeta' in str(tree.getroot()):
                log=open(rootDir+'\\'+log_name+'anzmeta_xml_log.txt','a')
                log.write(':;:'+seperator+str(x)+seperator+fl+seperator)
                print xmltaglist
                for xmltag in xmltaglist:
                    if xmltag not in tree:
                        print str(xmltag)+"::DoesNotExist"
                        log.write(str(xmltag)+"::DoesNotExist"+seperator)
                    for element in tree.iter(xmltag):
                        #print element[x]
                        for child in element.getchildren():
                            print "{0.tag}: {0.text}".format(child)
                            log.write("{0.tag}".format(child)+"::"+"{0.text}".format(child).replace('\n','')+seperator)
                log.write('^;:;\n')
                log.close
            else:
                print fl+" not an anzlic metadata file...logging seperately"
                log=open(rootDir+'\\'+log_name+'non_anzmeta_xml_log.txt','a')
                log.write(':;:'+seperator+str(x)+seperator+fl+seperator)
                for xmltag in xmltaglist:
                    for element in tree.iter(xmltag):
                        #print element[x]
                        for child in element.getchildren():
                            print "{0.tag}: {0.text}".format(child)
                            log.write("{0.tag}".format(child)+"::"+"{0.text}".format(child).replace('\n','')+seperator)
                log.write('^;:;\n')
                log.close


locatexml(SourceDIR,x, rootDir,xmllist, xmltaglist) #run locate xml and process to get sorted list of all tags
processxmlfile (xmllist, xmltaglist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply output the tag::text pairs in alphabetical order.  Then you'll be guaranteed to have a consistent ordering, and if all records have the same set of tags, they'll be in the same order.

Comment: The issue is that they don't all have the same tags or the same order. Rather than working in the original script to deconstruct the xml's what do you think of the following? Read the output text file, Create an array which has all the tags from the output text file, order them alphabetically and then run through each row (creating a single new text file) where it fills in  the tags from that array with blank entries where they don't exist.